# How can I send a session from the test code to the API controller in Junit5?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

My develop environment:

- Java 11
- Spring Boot 2.7.2
- Gradle
- Junit5
- Spring security & OAuth

My full code :

- https://github.com/SeolYoungKim/blog-aws-practice

My problems:

- The session is not delivered from my test code to the api controller.

When a user with Oauth2 authentication writes and save a post, it is registered as the author of the post based on user information stored in the session.

Actually, write and save logic works well without problems. But, I don't know how to deliver the session to the API controller in the test logic.

I tried the below ones. But, All failed.

- Use `@WithMockUser(roles = "USER") + MockHttpSession` -> Session delivered as null.
- Use `Only MockHttpSession` -> 302 redirection to `/login`
- Use `@WithSecurityContext` -> 403 forbidden error

I want to send a session from the test code to the API controller.

Below are my codes.

Test code:

```java
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@WithMockUser(roles = "USER")
class PostApiControllerTest {
    @DisplayName("save a post")
    @Test
    void save_post() throws Exception {
        //given
        User user1 = User.builder()
                .userRole(Role.USER)
                .userPicture("picture")
                .userEmail("email")
                .username("kim")
                .build();


        userRepository.save(user1);

        MockHttpSession mockHttpSession = new MockHttpSession();
        mockHttpSession.setAttribute("user", new SessionUser(user1));

        RequestAddPost post = RequestAddPost.builder()
                .title("title")
                .content("content")
                .categoryName("")
                .build();

        //then
        mockMvc.perform(post("/write")
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(post))
                        .session(mockHttpSession))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title").value("title"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content").value("content"))
                .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

API controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostApiController {

    private final PostService postService;

    @PostMapping("/write")
    public ResponsePost writePost(@Validated @RequestBody RequestAddPost requestAddPost,
                                  @LoginUser SessionUser user) {
        return postService.savePost(requestAddPost, user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find resource-server configuration in your code (just oauth2Login). You need it: `@RestController` secured with OAuth2 is a resource-server by definition (and login management should be a concern of clients, not resource-servers which only care if requests are authorized or not)

`@WithMockUser` populates test security-context with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` which is not the type of `Authentication` you'll get in a resource server => don't use it. Use either `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt` from spring-security-test or `@WithMocjJwtAuth` from [spring-addons](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)

### PS

You'd better switch to Java 17, it will be (very soon) the minimum for coming Spring versions

You should visit [this tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) to configure your resource-server, it might save you quite some time.

Comment: Thank you very mush for your reply.
I'll try them, and consider using Java17 that you recommended.